# Web Reference Breaks SSIS Package

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am working on a SSIS Package using SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2010 Shell.

I need to use a web method in a script task I have and I was able to run this script on windows 7 without any problems. This web service requires a certificate which I have installed in my personal computer store.

However when I moved this project into Windows Server 2008 R2, the package breaks for apparently no reason. I have no compilation errors on the Error List and if build the script task it will succeed, however when I finish editing the script a message box will appear with this error message:

"Scripts contained in the package have compilation errors. Do you want to save changes?"

If I remove the web reference from the script task, this message wont appear.

The package won't run because of this. I checked for error details on the Event Viewer, but it only shows "Package  Failed" and no further details appear about this issue. Could this be related to a certificate issue? Is there an error log or way to know more details about what is causing the package to fail?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you have an issue with installing the certificate on the 2008 server? Not knowing anything of certs, is it possible the cert is accepted for your credentials but not for the server as a whole?

Comment: Since I do not have administrator privileges for this server, the certificate was installed for my user only. Could this be the cause?

Comment: It might be. Easiest way would be to log on to the box and run the package from the command line. If it works there, then you'll need the admin to install the cert in global space (or at least the space of the account running the package). You could also create a Credential and then a an agent proxy using your account. Then the package would run as you but from the context of sql agent. Not a long term solution but something to validate the package works fine in the other environment and the issue is the certificate not being available.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't just the security issue of certificates required by the web service itself that you have to worry about.

The SSRS web server will not allow loading assemblies that are marked as "unsafe"--which is pretty much anything that does I/O. I once added a reference to a .Net Forms assembly to an SSRS report in order to use its rich text functionality. It worked beautifully in Visual Studio, but once deployed to the SSRS web server, it would never run. I am certain it could be made to function, but due to other priorities I actually gave up the job as everything I tried didn't work.

Searching online for adding custom assemblies yields some useful information for getting custom assemblies working. Here are some of the crucial steps:

- Sign the assembly with a strong name, required because it is deployed to the GAC.
- Use the assembly-level attribute `[assembly:AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]` in the assembly so SSRS can use it.

A couple of likely resources are [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dknight/2012/01/26/ssrs-custom-code-with-external-assemblies/) and [here](http://salvoz.com/blog/2011/01/10/custom-assemblies-in-sql-server-reporting-services-2008-r2/).